# Linq join() - Join two entities and select one

Tags: c#, linq, join

Can someone please help me with the following linq query?

```
var userList = _context.Employee.AsQueryable();
var id = 1;
userList = userList                
           .Join(_context.EmployeePermission, 
                     ul => ul.EmployeeId,           
                     p => p.EmployeeId,             
               (userlist, perm) => new { Employee = userList, Permisson = perm }) 
            .Where(empAndPerm => empAndPerm.Permisson.Trading >= 1 && empAndPerm.Permisson.EmployeeId == id)
            .Select(x => x.Employee);
```

I am gettting following error;

```
Cannot implicitly convert type
'System.Linq.IQueryable<System.Linq.IQueryable<Models.Employee>>' to
'System.Linq.IQueryable<Models.Employee>'. Are you missing a cast?
```

How to resolve?

Comment: You don't need the `AsQueryable`.

Comment: use SelectMany instead of Select

Comment: @MohammadRezaRahimi `SelectMany` translated to sql query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have a Typographical error in your code

```
(userlist, perm) => new { Employee = userList, Permisson = perm })
```

**userList** must be replaced by **userlist**.  **userList** refers to `System.Linq.IQueryable` in first line:

```
var userList = _context.Employee.AsQueryable();
```

But **userlist** refer to the parameter of anonymous method which is correct item.

so the seventh line must be changed to:

```
(userlist, perm) => new { Employee = userlist, Permisson = perm })
```

**Postscript:**

your code needs some enhancements which are not in the scope of this question. these enhancements depend on your business requirements. but I mention some potential mistakes:

1. your employees are not distinct after select so there is a duplicate employee and it's a little strange.
2. you are using the same context and most of the time you can use navigation properties that are defined in the context instead of using join method manually.

this [DotnetFiddle Sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Sl7QCU) might help you to choose the best approach for your requirement.

Comment: Cheers Reza. That solves the issue. If you can please point out the code enhancements then it will be great. Note, that i need first line of code, var userList = _context.Employee.AsQueryable(); I made it simple and paste in stackflow, in my code it's more complicated and the original userList is filter down (on certain criteria) further in my code.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the ambiguity in `userlist` and `userList` just by not declaring the original `userList` variable. Just start off with

```
var id = 1;
var users = 
    _context.Employee
            .Join(_context.EmployeePermission, 
                  ul => ul.EmployeeId,           
                  p => p.EmployeeId,             
                  (userList, perm) => new { Employee = userList, Permisson = perm }) 
            .Where(empAndPerm => empAndPerm.Permisson.Trading >= 1 && empAndPerm.Permisson.EmployeeId == id)
            .Select(x => x.Employee);
```

Now there's no confusion with potential variable shadowing or capItalization issues.